# delphi remove . and .. from path

Tags: delphi, string, delphi-7, path

How can I remove the . and .. from a path in Delphi (not using .NET).
I need a function, so I can pass it something like 'c:\program files..\program files...', and I want the function to return to me 'c:\'.

Can Delphi do that on its own? Or do I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

SysUtils.ExpandFileName('c:\temp\.\test\..\test2')

It returns the absolute path with all relative parts removed.